# An invalid form control with name is not focusable. error when saving content

Tags: forms

I've added a hidden field to the User Profile page, which I set via script. When saving the form, I get the error,

```
An invalid form control with name='field_map_y[und][0][value]' is not focusable.
```

Which from research, seems fair enough, if the field was hidden AND required. But the field is not required, and when I check the field, I can confirm this.

```
<input type="number" id="edit-field-map-y-und-0-value" name="field_map_y[und][0][value]" value="171" size="12" class="form-text form-number">
```

When I made the field visible, the form saves successfully. The error only seems to occur in Chrone.

Any ideas on how to enable the form to save with the hidden value?

Comment: How did you add the field to the form?